# how string buffer helps in not wasting resources

Tags: string, function, dart

so basically the method of adding and handling string in general is being replaced with other ways because it causes confusion and waste of resources. 
i agree but i want to know what exactly causes this waste of resources...as said here.

> '..and you’re running on an implementation that doesn’t have
>   sophisticated code for handling strings you can end up doing a lot of
>   wasted allocations...'
>   [Link](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/m1-language-changes/#no-explicit-interfaces)
>   how string buffer method avoids this wasteful...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My explanation of this is coming from a Java / .NET background, however the same logic applies.

**1. You must learn the concept of mutable and immutable objects...**

Objects like Int32 / Integer are mutable objects, meaning they can be changed in their current memory location after instantiation. This is because regardless of the value of the object, it's size in memory does not need to change.

Strings are immutable objects which means that once they are allocated they cannot be changed in their current memory location. This is because by nature a string can be of arbitrary length, and therefore, every time the string changes length, the system/runtime must find a new location in memory to store the string.

**2. Concatenation vs. StringBuilder / StringBuffer**

Since strings are immutable, every concatenation forces reallocation of memory. Lets assume the following example uses ASCII encoding (1 byte per char)

```
var message = "Hello World";
```

At this point, the system has allocated 11 bytes of memory to store your string.

```
message += "Hello Universe";
```

At this point, the system must allocate another 14 bytes to your original string. Your existing 11 bytes of memory can no longer store your new string!

Why "*sophisticated code for handling strings*" (`StringBuffer` / `StringBuilder`) helps you!

every time you append a string to the buffer/builder, it allocates the memory once, and keeps a pointer to that string in memory. The next time you allocate a string, it does it in a new location, without affecting the last one. Once you have finished building your string, the buffer/builder, concatenates everything in once pass into a single string, therefore your string allocation is vastly reduced as you are not doing it every time you append something to your buffer/builder!

Example:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

builder.Append("Hello World");
```

At this point the builder has allocated 11 bytes, and leaves that allocation as-is!

```
builder.Append("Hello Universe");
```

At this point, the builder allocated another 14 bytes, leaving the last string in tact.

```
builder.ToString();
```

At this point the builder concatenates all the strings in memory into one single string!

**Summary:**

Concatenation is a waste of resources because:

1. The system/runtime must clean out old, de-referenced memory locations, this takes some CPU time. In Java/.NET its called garbage collection.
2. Every re-allocation of memory is a waste, until the garbage collector can go and clean it out!

Therefore, concatenation reduces performance of CPU and memory usage!

Comment: I get it, its obvious if you understand memory management...note to all  new programmers understand initalization, declaration, assignation & binary code